# How do I understand this sorting?

Tags: java

```
int i, j, temp, size = 4;
int[] bar= {6, 4, 7, 1};
for(i=0; i< size - 1; i++){
  for(j=i; j< size; j++) {
    if(bar[j] < bar[i]){
      temp = bar[j];
      bar[j] = bar[i];
      bar[i] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me make sense of this. How is it exactly sorting these numbers. I'm getting so confused.

If you want to know, in the program that I'm doing, in the first output for this loop the numbers come out as 1, 6, 7, 4. So please help me out and explain how it's sorting! Like step by step! Thanks!

Comment: Seems like bubble sort http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: Use of `watch` may help you to understand what values are stored while performing the operations, simply an C program with watch helps you understand this code very easily.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's easy.

Your initial array looks like {6, 4, 7, 1}.

1. i = 0.
2. j = i = 0.
3. Compare 0-element with 0-element, so compare 6 with 6. They are the same, do nothing.
4. j++; j = 1.
5. Compare 1-element with 0-element, so compare 4 with 6, 4 is smaller, swap them and array looks now like {4, 6, 7, 1}.
6. j++; j = 2.
7. Compare 2-element with 0-element, so compare 7 with 4. 7 is greater, do nothing.
8. j++; j = 3.
9. Compare 3-element with 0-element, so compare 1 with 4, 1 is smaller, swap them and array looks now like {1, 6, 7, 4}. So it's exactly as you described when internal loop is finished first time.
10. i++; i = 1.
11. j = i = 1.
12. Et cetera...

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely Bubble Sort:

**Starting array:** { 6, 4, 7, 1 }

**Index numbers:** 6 = bar[0], 4 = bar[1], 7 = bar[2], 1 = bar[3]

**Step 1:**

i = 0, j = 0, bar[i] = 6, bar[j] = 6

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) {...} // condition is not true so nothing happens
```

**Your array:** { 6, 4, 7, 1 }

*Increase **j** by 1.*

**Step 2:**

i = 0, j = 1, bar[i] = 6, bar[j] = 4

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) // condition is true, if loop starts
{
    temp = bar[j]; // bar[j] value is 4, temp value is now 4
    bar[j] = bar[i]; // bar[i] value is 6, bar[j] value is now 6
    bar[i] = temp; // temp value is 4, bar[i] value is now 4
}
```

**OUTCOME:** bar[i] = 4, bar[j] = 6 - as you can see values are swapped, that's all this loop does.

**Your array:** { 4, 6, 7, 1 }

*Increase **j** by 1.*

**Step 3:**

i = 0, j = 2, bar[i] = 4, bar[j] = 7

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) {...} // condition is not true so nothing happens
```

**Your array:** { 4, 6, 7, 1 }

*Increase j by 1.*

**Step 4:**

i = 0, j = 3, bar[i] = 4, bar[j] = 1

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) // condition is true, if loop starts
{
    temp = bar[j]; // bar[j] value is 1, temp value is now 1
    bar[j] = bar[i]; // bar[i] value is 4, bar[j] value is now 4
    bar[i] = temp; // temp value is 1, bar[i] value is now 1
}
```

**OUTCOME:** bar[i] = 1, bar[j] = 4

**Your array:** { 1, 6, 7, 4 }

*Increase **j** by 1.*

Since j value is now 4 and the size is 4 (j < size) condition inside your for loop is not true. That for loop ends, so outer for loop can continue.

**Step 5:**

*Increase **i** by 1.*

i = 1, j = 1, bar[i] = 6, bar[j] = 6

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) {...} // condition is not true so nothing happens
```

**Your array:** { 1, 6, 7, 4 }

*Increase **j** by 1.*

**Step 6:**

i = 1, j = 2, bar[i] = 6, bar[j] = 7

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) {...} // condition is not true so nothing happens
```

**Your array:** { 1, 6, 7, 4 }

*Increase **j** by 1.*

**Step 7:**

i = 1, j = 3, bar[i] = 6, bar[j] = 4

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) // condition is true, if loop starts
{
    temp = bar[j]; // bar[j] value is 4, temp value is now 4
    bar[j] = bar[i]; // bar[i] value is 6, bar[j] value is now 6
    bar[i] = temp; // temp value is 4, bar[i] value is now 4
}
```

**OUTCOME:** bar[i] = 4, bar[j] = 6

**Your array:** { 1, 4, 7, 6 }

*Increase **j** by 1.*

Value of j once again exceeds size and outer loop is started for the last time.

**Step 8:**

i = 2, j = 2, bar[i] = 7, bar[j] = 7

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) {...} // condition is not true so nothing happens
```

**Your array:** { 1, 4, 7, 6 }

*Increase **j** by 1.*

**Step 9:**

i = 2, j = 3, bar[i] = 7, bar[j] = 6

```
if(bar[j] < bar[i]) // condition is true, if loop starts
{
    temp = bar[j]; // bar[j] value is 6, temp value is now 6
    bar[j] = bar[i]; // bar[i] value is 7, bar[j] value is now 7
    bar[i] = temp; // temp value is 6, bar[i] value is now 6
}
```

**OUTCOME:** bar[i] = 6, bar[j] = 7

**Your array:** { 1, 4, 6, 7 }

In the next step j exceeds size value so inner for loop breaks and i value exceeds size-1 so the outer for loop breaks. Program has ended and array values are now sorted from the smallest to the largest number.

**BONUS:**

If you noticed, there's always one step when ***i*** equals ***j*** inside your inner for loop and that step is unnecessary since you're comparing the number in array to itself. Change inner loop condition from: `for(j=i; j< size; j++)` to `for(j=i+1; j< size; j++)` and the number of steps will be greatly reduced.

I hope that you can understand Bubble Sort now. Feel free to ask if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have already told the step by step analysis of your algorithm,so no use to go again step by step.

In short what its doing is its finding the minimum no in range [i,n] in each loop(by comparing each element by value at position i and placing the min among them at position i),and the process continues till the last element.

Thus for your case i.e:-6,4,7,1

after 1st iteration output will be 1,6,7,4(1 is min in range i[1,4])

after 2nd iteration output will be 1,4,7,6(4 is min in range i[2,4])

after 3rd iteration output will be 1,4,6,7(6 is min in range i[1,4])

For more info you can see this form of buuble sort http://www.cs.oswego.edu/~mohammad/classes/csc241/samples/sort/Sort2-E.html

Answer (score -1):

Google for **Bubble Sort.** Take a look here, for example: http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Sorting/Bubble_sort